# How to set session maxAge dynamically in nextjs using next-auth

Tags: session, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I am using next-auth in nextjs 13, I want to implement the remember me during the signin.
so i use next-auth signIn function to pass email and password.

now when I want set maxAge of the session in ...nextauth.ts, I can not pass/receive the rememberMe variable in nextauth.ts.

code: //nextauth.ts

```
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) =>{
return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    session: {
      strategy: 'jwt',
      // maxAge: req.body?.rememberMe ? 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 : 20
    },
})
}
```

when i submit the sign in form, and log the req in nextuath.ts file, the method is get. so how i can access the body i sent from form?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and couldn't find a solution. I will post my solution for what I did. I have used the server cookies and save remember me an option and access it inside the handler function if there is a better way please mention it.

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { Account, User as AuthUser } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";


const authOptions: any = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login', //(4) custom signin page path
  },
  // secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET == 'production',
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "credentials",
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },

      async authorize(credentials: any) {

        cookies().set('rememberMe', credentials.rememberMe);

        authOptions.session = { maxAge: 15 };
        const user = {
          id: credentials.username,
          name: credentials.username,
        };
        return user;
      },
    })
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account }: { user: AuthUser; account: Account }) {
      if (account?.provider == "credentials") {
        return true;
      }
    },
  }
};


const handler = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {

  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const rememberMe = cookieStore.get('rememberMe')

  let maxAge = 24 * 60 * 60;
  if (rememberMe) {
    maxAge = rememberMe.value == 'on' ? 24 * 60 * 60 * 90 : 24 * 60 * 60;
  }

  return NextAuth(req as unknown as NextApiRequest, res as unknown as NextApiResponse, {
    ...authOptions,

    session: { maxAge: maxAge }
  });
};

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```